# Android Language change using JetPack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to change locale of the application using jetpack compose function like below

```
  @Composable
 fun SetLanguage(position: Int) {
    val locale = Locale(
        when (position) {
            0 -> "ar"
            1 -> "en"
            2 -> "fr"
            else -> {
                "ar"
            }
        }
    )
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
    else
        configuration.locale = locale
    var resources = LocalContext.current.resources
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)

}
```

you can check the working example (without buttons or textfield ) here
https://github.com/MakeItEasyDev/Jetpack-Compose-Multi-Language-Support

but the problem that is not working with OutlinedTextField or Buttons as they dont change when this function is called even rightToLeft support is not working and i dont find a good alternative to this solution for my problem  as i cant recreate the activity in my project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem many developers make when starting out with Compose is believing that when a recomposition occurs, everything within the composable will get recomposed. This isn't true. Compose looks at the composable signature and tries to determine if anything changes from the last time it was called. Only when the parameter **values** change will the function be called. In the source code you posted on Github, it didn't include a button or outline text field to demonstrate the problem, so I added one. When you add a button like this:

```kotlin
Button(onClick = {}) {
     Text("Do Something")
}
```

the Text composable inside of the Button will only be called when the initial composition occurs. But when the Button is recomposed, the Text will not be recomposed because the last parameter in the Button function hasn't changed. Lambda functions don't change. In regard to your case, changing the language does initiate a recomposition of the button, but because the last parameter does not change, the content inside of the lambda (in this example, the Text composable) will never be called. To get around this, one solution is to make the string resource that is used by the Text composable mutable. Anything that is mutable will automatically cause any composable that uses it to recompose.

The following code is what I took from your Github project and added a button. Notice how the string resource id is made mutable and this mutable state is used inside the Text:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LanguageContentPortrait(
    selectedPosition: Int,
    onLanguageSelected: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val buttonTextResId by remember { mutableStateOf(R.string.hello) }

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalLayoutDirection provides
                if (LocalConfiguration.current.layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Rtl.ordinal)
                    LayoutDirection.Rtl
                else LayoutDirection.Ltr
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))
            ToggleGroup(selectedPosition = selectedPosition, onClick = onLanguageSelected)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.content),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )

                Button(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(stringResource(buttonTextResId))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So anywhere you use trailing lambda expressions including click event handlers and you need language-dependent changes to occur, you will need to add mutable states to those resources inside those lambdas as shown above.

Even though the solution above works, I can't recommend using it. Most apps will have a lot of language dependent components and having to create a mutable state for every resource string would be a pain. A better solution is to force your entire app to recompose whenever the language changes. Since Compose-only apps are generally only a single activity, it will cause the entire app to recompose. This will ensure that all screens recompose and force all the Text composables to recompose without the need to have a mutable state for each one. There are different ways you can force your app to recompose the entire UI tree. Unfortunately, Compose does not contain an API that lets you recompose the entire tree from scratch, so the only real solution is to restart the app.

Since your app is designed to work with device configuration changes such as language changes, you might want to check out a Compose framework I developed that was specifically designed to handle device configuration changes. It's called Jetmagic. It not only handles language changes but all the other changes like screen orientation, screen size, screen density and all the other configuration qualifiers that are used with the older view-based system. Jetmagic allows you to treat your composables like resources instead of just a bunch of functions and it handles them in the exact same way xml resources are handled under the view-based system using the same algorithm. The sample app included also shows how changing the device's system language (under Android's settings) or by changing the language programmatically, causes your composable UIs to recompose rendering the content in the correct language:

https://github.com/JohannBlake/Jetmagic

Comment: Thanks Mr.Johann as you can see i am a newbie in Jetpack Compose, anyway your answer  saved my day as i will check the Jetmagic, but still having problem with RightToLeft Support if you could help Have a nice day

Comment: @MohamedAmineAyachi What exactly isn't working with RTL? Is the text field suppose to enter text from right to left but isn't doing it?

Comment: RightToLeft is an option that switch the right to left in some languages like arabic so the text will start from the left then finish to the right, for english it's the opposite, in android (xml at least) this option is supported i dont know if its possible in compose

Comment: I updated the code to include support for RTL. You need to use both CompositionLocalProvider and LocalLayoutDirection. I tested this out and the layout will switch if you change to locale between LTR and RTL.

Comment: @Johann This code works when app restarts or activity recreated, I have an use case where i need to show changes on the fly. There is some button on clicking of it i need to change UI from LTR to RTL or vice versa. Can you add your inputs