# Android Jetpack Compose Language Switching via AppCompatDelegate is not working

Tags: android, internationalization, android-jetpack-compose, locale

I am trying to build an in-app language switcher for the app I am working on, but I have tried almost everything method available on Stackoverflow. I also tried Official guide from here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#api-implementation

Nothing seems to work. Here is the code on GitHub https://github.com/bauripalash/Pankti-Android

Here's the settings screen where I am changing the language

```kotlin
fun Context.findActivity() : Activity? = when(this){
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}

fun changeLanguage( context: Context , language: String ){
    context.findActivity()?.runOnUiThread {
        val appLocale = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(language)
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
        //context.findActivity()?.recreate()
    }

    //context.findActivity()?.recreate()
}
```

https://github.com/bauripalash/Pankti-Android/blob/ed8cc2a34a3c615b360860a3c6a3977b98742862/app/src/main/java/in/palashbauri/panktimob/views/SettingsScreen.kt#L103

And here's main activity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("bn"))
        AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales()[0]?.let { Log.i("MainView" , it.displayLanguage) }
        setContent {
            PanktiMobTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainView()


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Recreating the activity, doesn't work either.

I have tried almost every method i could find on Stackoverflow and elsewhere.

[Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated)

[How to trigger recomposition after updateConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991087/how-to-trigger-recomposition-after-updateconfiguration)

[How to force jetpack compose to recompose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66950978/how-to-force-jetpack-compose-to-recompose)

[Android Language change using JetPack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815023/android-language-change-using-jetpack-compose)

I know this type of question is being asked a lot here. But can someone help me here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inorder to Work, Change the **MaterialTheme** to **AppCompat** Theme in **Themes.xml** file in values folder.

> Check this blog for adding android
> localization or multilanguage from
> scratch - [click-here](https://fierydinesh.medium.com/multi-language-support-android-localization-in-app-and-system-settings-change-language-e00957e9c48c)

example :
**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!--    <style name="Theme.SatCat" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />-->
    <style name="Theme.SatCat" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

***UPDATE :
For Jetpack Compose,***

Even you add **android:theme="@style/Theme.SatCat"** of **MainActivity** in **AndroidManifest.xml**. it will only work above setContent{} of your ComponentActivity. because,we added our **MaterialTheme** inside **setContent{}**.

Solution :

- We have to change our MainActivity extends **ComponentActivity** into **AppCompatActivity**,and use theme as AppCompat Theme in Manifest.
- After we change its working in Jetpack Compose.
  [image]
- Another thing,In Your case go to **Settings** Screen **DropDown menu**, Once select any language you have to store that **code** not **name**
  [image]
  .
  .
  .

***More Info :***
if we use AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales() with **MaterialTheme**, Context is becomes NULL, so its not able to create **Locale Manager**.

[image]

the **Context** is null because of **sActivityDelegates** is empty.

Even I don't know what is **sActivityDelegates**
[image]

But, as soon as i change the Theme to **AppCompat**. its becomes working.

Tell us, if someone know about **sActivityDelegates**, and why its not adding when lifecycle in postCreate as they mention in Comments. it would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned,  but it is not working for me. If I set my device default language to Bengali, it works, but otherwise not working

Comment: updated my answer.check it now.

Comment: I created an issue on google's issue tracker for this issue. It looks like a bug to me. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258907847

Comment: dirty but works

Answer (score 0):

`AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales()` work fine with debug version
but in release it does not change interface language (release version `setApplicationLocales` works with android emulator)

Comment: after long searches I add in build.gradle (:app)

`bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
}`