# Android change app language not working in Play Store version, but release build is ok

Tags: android, localization, resources

I implemented the in app language change by this comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75234169

I tested on some device and emulators and worked all of them, debug and release build also. I created the aab file, uploaded in the google play console and published, but when I downloaded it from the Play Store, the language change didn't work :O
After that I tried the Signed Universal APK from the console and I got same problem.
How can it be? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I foudd the solution here:

[Android Jetpack Compose Language Switching via AppCompatDelegate is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411797/android-jetpack-compose-language-switching-via-appcompatdelegate-is-not-working#comment136389178_77285636)

```
 bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
```